# Python function outside of SPSS syntax

Tags: python, spss

I'm trying to remove some SPSS Multiple response sets with Python.
The following is saved in a SPSS syntax and is working as long as I have the names of the sets in the "list.txt" file (in the directory of the syntax):

```
begin program.
import spss, spssaux, SpssClient, os, sys
SpssClient.StartClient() 
working_directory_path = os.path.dirname(SpssClient.GetDesignatedSyntaxDoc().GetDocumentPath()) 
SpssClient.StopClient()
def delete_function(dir_path, filename):
    path_file = str(dir_path) + "\\" + filename
    print path_file
    with open(path_file) as f:
        result = ["$" + x.replace('\n',"") for x in f.readlines()]
    names = [x for x in spss.GetMultiResponseSetNames()]
    for i in result:
        if i in names:
            spss.Submit('MRSETS /DELETE NAME=[{}].'.format(unicode(i, "utf-8")))
    print(spss.GetMultiResponseSetNames())
delete_function(working_directory_path, 'list.txt')
end program.
```

But when I move the function outside of the syntax (in a separate "function.py" file), I can't make it work.
Any ideas?

Comment: it would really help if you posted the error which you are getting.

Comment: When I move the function outside of the .sps file and run the syntax against the data file, I get the following error:
"NameError: global name 'spss' is not defined" - guess you are correct about the python not recognizing the spss.Submit. I'll use the syntax as it is for now - when I have more time, I will try to re-work the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

The Python which you installed with SPSS is supposed to be working within the SPSS environment - i.e. the Python code to be run from an SPSS syntax. Which I understand it works fine for you.

If you move the code outside your SPSS environment, some lines of codes won't make sense. For example, the `BEGIN PROGRAM/END PROGRAM` are SPSS commands, not Python commands. They tell SPSS that there is Python code between them. They make no sense for Python.

Depending on which Python installation you are using when trying to run your `function.py`(SPSS-Python, or standalone Python), some modules might not be available (`spss, spssaux, SpssClient`). They are not bundled into the standard Python library, they are only available with the SPSS-Python.

Furthermore, in your code:

- you are referencing an SPSS syntax, which may not be open when you run it from outside SPSS
- you are trying to run some SPSS syntax code (`spss.Submit`), which again may result in an error

And there are probably a dozen more reasons why your idea is problematic :)

Bottom line: you can't just take code out of SPSS and run it into python. You have to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your python functions into a seperate script and import them into SPSS like so:

```
begin program. 

import sys
sys.path.append("C:\SomeDirectory") # directory containing the function.py file

import spss 
import function

function.delete_function(working_directory_path, 'list.txt')

end program.
```

Now you can call the function without defining it in the SPSS-syntax. Mind you, imported like above, you call the function after the module name "function.delete_function()"

Im not sure whether this is what you want or whether you want to run your script from an external Python-IDE. If so, this might help you:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.python.help/spss/programmability_option/python_package_xdrives.htm